# Hide/Show UILabel with hidden property not working

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uilabel

I implemented the following code in my CustomViewController's method viewDidLoad to switch a label visibility on/off depending on my needs:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
 [super viewDidLoad];

 myLabel.hidden=NO;

if (x==1) {

   myLabel.hidden=YES;//here is correctly hidden
}
else {
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:myLabel];

    if(!myLabel.hidden){

      NSLog(@"I'm not hidden!");// the log displays correctly! so myLabel is not Hidden but I can't see it!
      [self.view bringSubviewToFront:myLabel];
    }
}
```

MyLabel is declared in CustomViewController.h ("IBOutlet UILabel *myLabel;") and connected to its corresponding UILabel interface in the Xib file.

Why Can't I see it even if its "hidden"property is false?

P.s the UILabel text is assigned to the UILabel interface in the xib file

thanks
Luca

**solved** thanks guys I feel stupid.the label was out of the stage so I could see it.I just repositioned it and now it is working fine

Comment: Is the label a direct subview of your main view, or have another ancestor?

Comment: Have you set any text to the `UILabel`? Also, make sure the text color is different from the background color..

Comment: One more thing... You say that your label is declared as `infoPostRist` correct? Or we're talking for another label?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the sake of knowledge I answer my own question:the problem was that the label was out of the stage so I couldnt see it.I just repositioned it and now it is working fine

Answer (score 6):

You got a typo in your code:
Your outlet seems to be `myLabel` but your `if` statement using `mylabel` (Should be with an Uppercase 'L'). Also note that the getter for this property is `isHidden` and not `hidden` as you might expected (this is not the source of the problem though, but Apple stating it in their documentation so I thought it was worth mentioning).

**EDIT:**

You said:

> MyLabel is declared in CustomViewController.h ("IBOutlet UILabel *infoPostRist;") and connected to its corresponding UILabel interface in the Xib file.

So, shouldn't you check `infoPostRist` instead of `myLabel` then?

Comment: No that's just my mistake to copy it in here.

Comment: Oh ok. Back to square one then XD

Answer (score 0):

You can try to remove it from the view instead :

```
[myLabel removeFromSuperview];
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try your code in `(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated` or `- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated`?

Hiding/Showing views when the view controller is loaded may not work properly.